# mvc database first issues with edmx/relationships and view showing id field

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

my task is very simple, i need to create a library mvc web app that allows crud operations, the only constraints are that 1 book can have multiple authors and can also have multiple publishers.

to accomplish this, this is my database model:

[image]

and the respective sql code for the books->books_authors->authors table relationships, the publishers relationship is defined in the same way

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BOOKS](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[TITLE] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[PAGES] [int] NOT NULL,
[SYNOPSIS] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[PUBLISHDATE] [date] NOT NULL,
[ISBN] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[SUBJECT] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_BOOKS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BOOKS_AUTHORS](
[BOOKID] [int] NOT NULL,
[AUTHORID] [int] NOT NULL,


CONSTRAINT [PK_BOOKS_AUTHORS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BOOKID] ASC,
    [AUTHORID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BOOKS_AUTHORS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BOOKS_AUTHORS_AUTHORS] FOREIGN KEY([AUTHORID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AUTHORS] ([ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BOOKS_AUTHORS] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BOOKS_AUTHORS_AUTHORS]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BOOKS_AUTHORS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BOOKS_AUTHORS_BOOKS1] FOREIGN KEY([BOOKID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BOOKS] ([ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BOOKS_AUTHORS] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BOOKS_AUTHORS_BOOKS1]
GO




CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AUTHORS](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FIRSTNAME] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [LASTNAME] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AUTHORS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**now onto my issues, when i add a ado.net model to the mvc web app, the edmx looks like this:**

[image]

**i thought i defined a 1 to many relationship between BOOKS and BOOKS_AUTHORS/BOOKS_PUBLISHERS, why is it now showing up on the edmx?**

**my other issue is that given the above edmx model, when i create a scaffolded controller with views, the create action lists the ID field from BOOKS as an input instead of hiding it while on the index action the same ID field is hidden, like so:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: is your id field is auto generated ?

Comment: i have done it on the primary tables but i'm still struggling with the relationship tables i.e BOOKS_AUTHORS, on this table both columns have to be marked as primary key, correct? do i need to do anything else to the relationship tables?

Comment: you made it primary key with auto increment / identity ?

Comment: only on BOOKS, AUTHORS and PUBLISHERS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework edmx, do not show the Reference Relationship Table.
that is why Its showing Many to Many relationship between book and authors

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742359.aspx) it is pure join table

2nd Issue is because, you have not defined your primary key as Identity (Auto Generated)

Comment: i'm correcting it now on all the main tables excluding the relationship tables. are the composite keys defined correctly and should they also be defined as Identity?

Comment: yes, cos then only edmx will understand that user won't have to enter it, as primary key can not be null

Comment: but on the BOOKS_AUTHORS table i can only choose one of the columns to be the identity column, i know that both BOOKID and AUTHORID have to be a composite primary key

Comment: None of them will be identity on that table as its just a pure join table which we say as referential table as well

Comment: glad it helped @user2983177

Answer (score 1):

In EDMX file that's not Relationship, that shows Navigation property ,
it allows you to navigate from one entity to a "connected" entity

while using `Book` table yo can navigate to `author` table like

`var a=(from d in _db.Book.Include(AUTHOR)...)` 
it will include author table to use in same Linq

for second query make your Id field auto Generated.

Comment: does that mean i have to add the fields "first name", "last name" and "publisher name" manually to the index view?

Comment: by scaffolding ,index page will be generated according to the class generated by EF .So if something is not there in your Book class and you want it , you have to create a new model Class which will have all the data you required on Index page.

Comment: @user2983177 yes i think so

Comment: i have several questions about the viewmodel approach so i'll create a new question and link people to this one

Comment: @Viplock could you check my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882018/mvc-use-viewmodel-to-display-data-from-multiple-tables-and-perform-crud-operatio